# Software centre image link is broken

Tags: support

The software centre image is often used when explaining how to install software, [like this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37083/how-can-i-change-the-unity-launcher-delay/64100#64100) (I fixed this one on the original page):

---

In Ubuntu 11.10 it is now possible to change the edge reveal time out using [compiz-config-settings-manager](http://packages.ubuntu.com/compiz-config-settings-manager) [Install compiz-config-settings-manager http://bit.ly/software-small](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compiz-config-settings-manager).

---

As you can see, the image link is broken.

The bitly link for the software centre is broken:

```
http://bit.ly/software-small
```

It points to

```
http://i.imgur.com/oRhB2.png
```

instead of

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRhB2.png
```

I don't know much about bitly, but [it looks like](https://bitly.com/software-small+) it was posted by marcoceppi. If he's out there, can he change it? Otherwise, all instances need to be changed.

Or, if we had a template for apt packages, that would be a good replacement.

[image: Screenshot]

---

```
wget https://bitly.com/software-small
--2011-10-20 01:55:03--  https://bitly.com/software-small
Resolving bitly.com... 69.58.188.33, 69.58.188.34
Connecting to bitly.com|69.58.188.33|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved
Location: http://i.imgur.com/oRhB2.png [following]
--2011-10-20 01:55:04--  http://i.imgur.com/oRhB2.png
Resolving i.imgur.com... 93.184.221.133
Connecting to i.imgur.com|93.184.221.133|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2011-10-20 01:55:04 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Comment: Hmm -- I had chalked this one up to the content filtering at my work, but it looks more widespread than I realized.  For me, works from home, not from work.

Comment: Related: [Change the Software Icon](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1917/change-the-software-icon)

Comment: Still broken as of today, can we do anything to troubleshoot or help? I voted in the linked post above.

Answer (score 9):

A hotfix has been created, going forward the following urls should be utilized:

```
http://hostmar.co/software-small
http://hostmar.co/software-large
```

They will *always* map to the appropriate Software Center icon.

---

Stack Exchange is aware of this and a fix is in the works with no ETA at this time.

---

This appears to be an issue with certain ISPs, while the root cause is unknown, it appears to affect a large part of the community. As a result I've updated the bit.ly link to point to a different URL of the same image.

[image]

---

The image links isn't broken.

[image]

[image]

Not sure how else to replicate this. The image isn't hosted on the Stack Exchange imgur account - it's hosted in my personal imgur account. <strike>Furthermore you can not change a bit.ly URL map once it's been created. So even if it wasn't working I still wouldn't be able to update the shortcut.</strike> Rechecked, you can't edit the link.

Comment: I have the same problem as pydave, I've added [a screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uviiL.png) to his original post. Could it be working for you because you're logged in or something?

Comment: @fluteflute Even in incognito, it shows up.

Comment: Do we need a custom URL redirect for this image? (By that I mean should we be using a special URL *within* our control that we can redirect to whatever image we need?)

Comment: The image is reported as “no longer available” for me at home as well. It works from a different ISP in the same country.

Comment: I will get in touch with Stack Exchange to see if they can community with imgur about the issue.

Comment: I am getting the same issue, Marco. Every so often it doesn't load up. Can whoever owns the bit.ly links change the URLs so they are `i.stack.imgur.com` instead of just `i.imgur.com`

Comment: From where I am right now, http://i.imgur.com/oRhB2.png gives me “no longer available”, and [I'm not the only one](http://superuser.com/revisions/230764/2). Could you try changing to an `i.stack.imgur.com` image?

Comment: @Gilles No, You can not change the link in bit.ly.

Comment: @MarcoCeppi Wait, I'm confused. That's what you said earlier, then you struck it out and said you'd updated the bit.ly link.

Comment: @Gilles I was mistaken and corrected later on. You can change the links TITLE, not the actual link though.

Comment: Oh. It's annoying that this often-used image is broken for many visitors. Have you contacted Imgur? Do you think we should ask the SE devs for a mass-edit to a different link?

Comment: @Gilles I'll be speaking with SE today about it - see what options are availalble

Comment: @MarcoCeppi Any progress on this? The images are still broken.

Comment: I should note that this doesn't only happen to software center images. It also affects certain screenshots, as well.

Comment: @ScottSeverance The screenshots are a different issue, can you please open a new meta post about those when you come across them? There should be an easy fix for those.