# Image link cleanup for HTTPS

Tags: discussion, image, https

As you may have read by now, [the roadmap to HTTPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291947/270345) will involve some manual fixing of dead links to images and uploading images from other sources to imgur. Sooner or later this is going to come our way, so let's get cracking ***now***. The SE devs have a list of posts for MSE, but for the rest of us, [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/430352/posts-with-inline-http-images-not-from-imgur?StartDate=2009-12-01&EndDate=2017-01-01) can be used to keep track of posts (unless we can come up with better ideas).

There would be *thousands* of such posts, so we would need to pace ourselves to avoid burnout and flooding the active questions list.

---

For non-imgur non-HTTPS links, the guidance is to upload to imgur where possible:

[image]

The "upload to imgur" link opens the image upload dialog with the link pre-populated.

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning what should be done to images that don't have HTTPS equivalents. ([This one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/286971/hdd-makes-high-pitched-noise-in-windows-but-it-is-silent-in-ubuntu/286980#286980) for example.) Should I upload to imgur? Should it be flagged for removal?

Comment: @NathanOsman for problem 1, upload to imgur. For problem 2, we have time to get support for HTTPS in hostmar.co, since the change will start from MSO and MSE, then move to one select SE site and then to all sites.

Comment: Isn't it already impossible to upload non-HTTPS images? If so, problem 2 already exists.

Comment: What should we do if there's a [video](http://askubuntu.com/questions/614588/graphical-glitches-after-updating-14-10-to-15-04) or an image that imgur says is not supported? (Thank you for posting this!)

Comment: @Zanna are you talking about the GIF? Gifycat supports HTTPS, so we can just change the protocol. For others, we can skip embedding and just keep a link. Or try to convert/compress. I'll try the latter.

Comment: I think relying on the results from the SEDE query might a bit challenging since the results won't be updated until Monday. Wouldn't it be better to export the list of posts and add them in a answer to this question? This way, every time someone fixes a post, they would remove the link from the answer. We can then re-export the list on Monday when the SEDE data is updated.

Comment: @Dan posted a list of links, the top ones might have already been edited.

Comment: Actually, most of this is not necessary. Stack Exchange will run a bot to migrate http images to https where the image location supports https. They've already done a trial run [on Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity). What needs to be handled manually is content where the server doesn't support https, and that's best done after the bot has run.

Comment: Is this a process that a low rep user can assist in? I don't know if doing the edits, and having them get added to a queue for review is actually saving work for others or not. Still, I could add my effort to the project in odd times here and there, if appropriate. In addition, I can also use GIMP to convert GIFs to PNG/JPG. Or, as @Gilles suggests, is it too soon to get started with this?

Comment: @Seth as I mentioned to muru in chat, the broken image links query we used before only found bit.ly/software-small, and the bit.ly/software-large ones still need to be fixed. Should I change those links to hostmar.co now?

Comment: @zanna wait until Marco adds https support, so we don't have to edit them twice.

Comment: Actually, looks like he's done that, so go ahead.

Comment: The bit.ly ones *should* be all gone now, so I will be shifting my efforts to the etherpad (been doing it, but very very slowly)

Answer (score 4):

List of posts (once you edit a post, remove the http:// so that it's no longer a link, add `i` after if the Software Center icon is a problem). If an image is dead, do check `http://web.archive.org/web/*/<imgurl>` to see an archive is available. If it is, then upload the archive, please.

## Update the list in https://etherpad.net/p/au-img-cleanup

I modified the SEDE query to exclude hostmar.co and bit.ly/software-* links, which leaves 916 posts, of which 584 haven't been touched by Community. Some of those are tag wikis, which I have fixed.

Do remember to check http://web.archive.org is a link is dead, it might be available in the archive. You can go to `http://web.archive.org/web/*/<url>` (for example, `http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://web.githlar.net/gdp_1.png`)

Comment: @ElderGeek SE has already fixed the easy ones. Check Community's activity from today morning. And Marco has added HTTPS to hostmar.co, so all that's left to do is for this list to be updated. I ran a quick check, and there are about 500 posts left, but SEDE hasn't been updated yet

Comment: @muru I won't be able to get back for several hours as I have an appointment with a prospective client out of town this morning. I'll check back when I can, but must prepare to leave now.

Comment: @muru Perhaps a daft question but how do I go about "Check Community's activity from today morning"? I cleaned up a few of the icon issue problems on the [etherpad](https://etherpad.net/p/au-img-cleanup) list but if a script has yet to run through changin http to https that's likely a waste of time.

Comment: SEDE data dump will be Sunday around UTC 0700 or 0800 if I'm not wrong, so we can wait until then at least (cc @ElderGeek)

Comment: I'm slightly worried about the bit.ly links (which I'm fixing) muru, I don't want people to get confused. When the data gets updated maybe I could use my query to cut them out of your list?

Comment: @Zenna I'm checking the revision histories of posts returned by http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/edit/638497 (which skips bit.ly/software-* and hostmar.co from the check) using curl. Got rate limited before, so doing it 1/s now. Will update the post with these.