# Can we fix these posts with missing images essential to the answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, image

I've had a really long [https image cleanup](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16805/image-link-cleanup-for-https) hangover, but today I am finally closing [this tab](https://etherpad.net/p/au-img-cleanup).

However, there were two things that nobody managed to fix - highly upvoted answers with missing images that were essential to understanding:

- I *think* this one is OK now. **Many thanks to muru & terdon** <del>I spent quite a while trying to reproduce what [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88391/whats-an-uppercase-t-at-the-end-of-unix-permissions/88428#88428) must have shown, but I can't find any view in Caja (MATE's file browser) that shows the sticky bit (although the permissions tab in the properties does show the executable bit), and Nautilus users I asked were also unable to find it. Is there any way to show the difference between a directory with and a directory without an x bit that also shows that they both have the sticky bit in Nautilus? (Hmm. That's not a meta question is it?!) Or have I totally misunderstood?</del>
- **Fixed by Takkat**  <del>Since my sound card is finally detected (thanks to awesome hackers) I was able to have a go at reproducing the images for [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81894/desktop-install-with-audigy-soundcard-no-sound-errors-in-syslog/82181#82181), but I only have three screens in my alsamixer, and it seems to be about changing something in the *fifth* one, so I'm stumped.</del>

To be honest I'd probably have voted to delete these answers after leaving comments asking for the post authors to fix them and seeing that they had been ignored (the authors are both active users it seems, but ignored multiple comments asking them to repair the images), if they were not highly upvoted posts.

Can we fix them? What should I be doing in these cases?

Comment: That sound Q apparently is a wall of screenshots on just about how to unmute a given card using alsamixer. In case we want to keep that Q&A (1000 views in 5 years only) a single shot would probably do.

Comment: I'm not sure what the permissions screenshots were supposed to show. I booted up a 10.04 VM and the only place where Nautilus shows the `t` is in List view, if you enable the permissions column: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvKaK.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztIIq.png

Comment: @muru thanks a lot for your efforts! Yeah I'm really mystified still, since as far as I can see that list view is exactly as illuminating as the `ls -l` output *in the question*. But maybe that was it. I can't think of anything else it could be than what you have in your two images.

Comment: Added some shots to the ALSAMIXER answer.

Comment: Thank you @Takkat :D that's awesome

Comment: For the first one, since the entire section mentioning the images is useless without the images, I just removed it leaving the wikipedia link.

Comment: Perhaps muru's images are better than nothing @terdon? Now since the answer looks kind of OK, I think maybe the 12 upvotes were for explaining what the sticky bit is rather than some dazzling demonstration of the difference between big t and little T in nautilus...

Comment: Sure. If someone wants to add them.

Comment: I think I've fixed it! This time when I edited it (third attempt) I finally saw why nautilus (or er caja) is more informative than `ls`, by fiddling around and setting different permissions on the directories.

Comment: @Zanna I've replaced your images with the same, but the mouse edited out, and the black replaced with red outlines. Feel free to revert

Comment: @Tim great job! Thanks a lot for your help :)